# Insert function inside another one by using parameter

Tags: javascript, html, css, function, hide

How to run this external function inside some outer function by inputing it?

```js
function function1(a){
  a;  
}

somefunction(function (){
  $('#div1').hide();alert('hi');
});
```

Comment: Given `a` being the parameter for a passed function you simply use `a()` inside or better return its return `function function1(a){return a}`, depending on your usecase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to execute the `external function` inside an `outer function` by inputing it, you can pass the reference of the `external function` to the `outer function` and then invoke the function in the `outer function`

Like this :

```js
function externalFunction(outerFunctionReference){
  // invoking the given function
  outerFunctionReference();
}

function firstOuterFunction() {
  console.log("Hello from the first outer function");
}

// passing the first outer function reference
externalFunction(firstOuterFunction);

// passing the second outer function reference
externalFunction(function secondOuterFunction() {
  console.log("Hello from the second outer function");
});
```